# How do I save lineage info in Apache Atlas when using Apache Cassandra and Elasticsearch

Tags: cassandra, apache-atlas

I am planning to deploy Apache Atlas using Apache Cassandra as a storage backend and Elasticsearch as an index backend. I am wondering how I can save lineage info with this? It provides get API to get the lineage info but seems to have no way to save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Atlas lineage is created when they are linked through processes using inputs and outputs.

Example:
If you want to see a lineage between two hive_table types it would be like:

`T1(hive_table)--->P1(hive_process)--->T2(hive_table)`

So,basically the entities need to be linked through a process type.

In Atlas processes are entities and can be created using the API `POST: /v2/entity` with inputs and outputs defined in them like for above `hive_process`:

```
POST: /api/atlas/v2/entity
    {
      "entity": {
        "typeName": "hive_process",
        "attributes": {
          "outputs": [
            {
              "guid": "2", 
              "typeName": "hive_table",
              "uniqueAttributes": {
                "qualifiedName": "t2@primary"
              }
            }
          ],
          "qualifiedName": "p1@primary",
          "inputs": [
            {
              "guid": "1",
              "typeName": "hive_table",
              "uniqueAttributes": {
                "qualifiedName": "t1@primary"
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "P1-Process"
        }
      }
    }
```

Important thing to note before creating the process is that referenced entities(inputs,outputs) should pre-exists,else process creation will fail.

If your requirement doesn't consist of pre-existing types you can of course go ahead and define your own types for Atlas Entity and Process

More about Atlas type system on [Apache site](https://atlas.apache.org/#/TypeSystem)